# Postgres 13 - default privileges NOT working

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I have a schema "test_db" and a role "test_user" and I'd like to strip DELETE privilege from "test_user" on all tables in the schema "test_db" - how to achieve this? If possible I'd like to not resort to triggers / rules.

What I tried so far is to set up DEFAULT PRIVILEGES as a postgres on schema to this user: I tried both *granting* only select and update or *revoking* delete priv, but still, if I log into as a "test_user" I can delete from tables in this schema.

Here is the statement I used:

```
alter default privileges for role postgres in schema test_db
   revoke delete, truncate on tables from test_user;
```

Comment: Altering the default privileges will change the privileges on *future* tables created by a certain user, not the existing tables.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, I know, thanks,  I'm doing this at the db initialization stage, so there's no tables yet.

Comment: @zizu_zaza So how (and with what role) are you creating the tables? How does the `test_user` gain access to them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SQL statement will do nothing useful, since `test_user` doesn't have any privileges on tables newly created by `postgres` anyway, so revoking those privileges is unnecessary and won't have any effect.

To revoke the privileges from *existing* tables, use

```
REVOKE DELETE, TRUNCATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA test_db FROM test_user;
```